# Unable to loop thru JSON array inside an object

Tags: python, json

This is how my JSON return object looks like:

```
{
    u'Policy': u'{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [{
            "Sid": "xxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "yyyyyyy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx/AWSLogs/00000000/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }]
    }',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'content-length': '479',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'date': 'Thu,
            06Oct201602: 07: 48GMT',
            'server': 'AmazonS3',
            'x-amz-id-2': 'xxxxxxx',
            'x-amz-request-id': 'xxxxxxx'
        },
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HostId': 'xxxxxxx',
        'RequestId': 'xxxxxxx',
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to loop thru Statements:

```
for stmt in bucket_policy['Policy']['Statement']:
   print stmt
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is it because the return data is Unicode or something wrong with the way I am looping?

Comment: Trying to replicate, but the sample data you are providing is invalid.

Comment: Your data is neither JSON nor a Python structure, it's a mix of both. You will need to parse the JSON part separatly.

Comment: it is supposed to be a JSON document: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.BucketPolicy.policy

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the JSON into a dictionary with

```
import json
mydict = json.load(bucket_policy)
```

Then loop:

```
for stmt in mydict['Policy']['Statement']:
   print stmt
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it's shown in your question, `bucket_policy['Policy']` contains a string, not a dictionary.

Either define it as a dictionary (i.e. get rid of `u'` at the beginning and `'` at the end) or parse the JSON with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).